# Interaction - pion to tau and antineutrino

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

$$
\pi^{-} \to \tau^{-}+\overline{\nu}_{\tau}
$$

So, this interaction (reaction) is supposed to be forbidden. But, can not see what should be wrong here.

Charge is conserved.
Baryon number is fine.
Even if I check the lepton numbers, everything works.

Do I see something wrong, or I forgot some conservation law?

Answer (score 5):

There simply isn't enough energy. A tau lepton is heavier than a proton ($1777\,\mathrm{MeV}$), so it can't be a decay product of a pion which only has a mass of about $140 \,\mathrm{MeV}$.

And you can't fix it by boosting the meson to high speed because the same consideration still applies in the rest frame of the pion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.@dmckee  I see that I need to pay more attention to energies.
I thought that barion, charge and lepton numbers could always tell me surely is the interaction possible,

Is it then the same if there is kaon going to pion?

$$
K^{-} \to \pi^{-}
$$

Then, here it should be the same? Kaon has too much energy to decay only to negative pion?

Comment: Just so you know... it’s “baryon”, not “barion”. (I fixed it in your question, and in your previous question.)

Comment: My mistake, thanks! @G.Smith :)

Comment: A single particle of one mass cannot become a single particle of a different mass, because energy would not be conserved.

Comment: By the way, there are some other conserved or mostly-conserved quantum numbers, like weak isospin.

Comment: It's much simpler if you think about it in terms of conservation of invariant mass rather than energy (with momentum as an afterthought)